# Best way to preload SVG image tags?

Tags: caching, svg, d3.js

I'm building an SVG-based visualization that (partially) relies on showing many images in quick succession. The images can't be fetched fast enough from the network, so they must be preloaded.

My understanding is that SVG doesn't properly cache `image` tags, at least in major browsers. So JavaScript preloading librairies and techniques (eg. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)) won't work.   (I could resort to using layered HTML `img` tags, but because of the specifics of my application, I would like to stick to pure SVG as much as possible)

I see two options:

- Encoding the PNG image data as base64, storing it in memory as strings and using the strings to iteratively populate `image` tags using `data:image/png;base64`.
- Layering many SVG groups on top of each other with all but one set to `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` and iteratively unhiding the appropriate group. However, I believe it won't be possible to programatically detect that all images have finished preloading.

What's the best way to preload the image data? Perhaps I've missed an easier option.

Comment: Does your vis have to be *all* SVG? If not, you might be able to preload the images as HTML, then overlay them on the vis... It won't work if you need them fully integrated, however, e.g. to apply clip paths.

Comment: Yes, as I mention in my question, I would much prefer if it were all SVG. (otherwise, it would require me to split my viz in two SVG layers so that the image layer be layered between them)

Comment: @DavidChouinard I know it is a REALLY old question, but actually the problem still persists   Did you ever find a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with the underlying mechanics of web browsers to know if this will work with svg `image` tags, but I had success caching images with new Image():

```
    //download low quality images
    var imageArray = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 600; i++){
        imageArray[i] = new Image();
        imageArray[i].src = moviePath + (i + 1) + '.jpg.t';
        imageArray[i].onload = function(){
            var i = this.src.split(movieName + '/')[1].split(".")[0];
            d3.select("#bar" + i).style("stroke", 'rgb(' + colors[i].rgb + ')');
        }
    }
```

To show an image, I just set the src of the displayed image to one that was already loaded and the browser loads it from its cache.

There is another small trick used later in the [source](https://github.com/1wheel/film-strips/blob/master/showMovie.js) - show a low quality image first and starting loading a high quality one only after a short timeout passes without another image being selected. Then, after the high quality image has loaded, show it only if the same image is still selected.

No idea if these are best practices or anything, but [it worked reasonably well](http://roadtolarissa.com/film-strips/).

Comment: I believe this is the exact approach I mentioned wouldn't work in my question. My understanding is that major browsers *do not* retrieve SVG `image`s from cache (bitmap support in SVG is somewhat an after-thought). Unless you can dispute that, I don't think this approach works for SVG.

Comment: UAs (and I only really have detailed knowledge of Firefox here) cache the (XML) data but not the bitmap representation of SVG images. I think that Opera will cache the bitmap if the buffered-rendering attribute is set. The above answer should therefore work in general.